# AWS CloudFront with Signed URL: 403 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm configuring an environment with a **Amazon S3 Bucket** for storage of media files and **Amazon CloudFront** for restricted distribution purposes.

The access to those media files needs to be private and should be done via a **signed URL**. So I created the **S3 Bucket** on `South America (São Paulo)` region and uploaded some test files. Then I created a **CloudFront Distribution** with that previous **bucket** as `Origin` and it's `Bucket Access` is **restricted**. I created a new **OAI** (Origin Access Identity) and also selected the option `Yes, Update Bucket Policy` so that it auto-configures the **S3** `Bucket Policies`.
I'm only using the **default** `Behavior` and it's configured with `HTTP and HTTPS` **viewer protocol policy** and `GET, HEAD` **allowed methods**. `Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies)` is set and the `Trusted Signer` is set to `Self`.

Here's some images to clarify the setup:

**S3 Bucket Policy**
[image: S3 Bucket Policy]

**Distribution's Origin**
[image: Distribution's Origin]

**Distribution's Behavior**
[image: Distribution's Behavior]

I'm getting a `HTTP 403` while trying to access the signed URL generated with either **awscli** or **cfsign.pl**

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Is there something missing that I don't know? It looks like I made everything the **docs** said to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After recreating both the **Amazon S3 Bucket** and **Amazon CloudFront Distribution** I was still experiencing the issue. After a session with my rubber duck I found out that the `Private Key` file that I was using belongs to a deleted `CloudFront Key-pair`.

Now that I'm using the correct key to encrypt things everything is working fine. That doesn't explain why the first **bucket** and **distribution** weren't working because in that specific case I was using the **same** set of configurations and the right `Private Key` file.

Answer (score 11):

I received the same `Access Denied` error and spent the last couple hours trying to figure out what was going on. I finally realized that the `Expires` parameter was set in the past since I was using my local time instead of UTC. Make sure to set the `Expires` in the future according to UTC.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was with URL I was passing to URL signing code (I was using **AWS SDK for Node.js**).

```
cloudFront.getSignedUrl({
  url: `${distributionUrl}/${encodeURI(key)}`,
  expires: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 60
})
```

Note `encodeURI`. I was not doing that. The resulting signed URL would still have URI components encoded, **BUT would have invalid signature**, thus causing 403 error.

EDIT: ...And you have to wrap it into `url.format()` like this:

```
cloudFront.getSignedUrl({
  url: url.format(`${distributionUrl}/${encodeURI(key)}`),
  expires: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 60
})
```

I guess they should be doing that in SDK.

Comment: Thank you so much! Already lost a few hairs on this one, haha

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue. Probably, we have to re-generate Clouf Front key-pair.

Comment: I don't know. but actually, After re-generated the key, the problem has been resolved.